# Como reutilizar os dados de uma tabela do bd com While dentro de um for

Tags: php

Estou tentando reutilizar os dados vindo do meu bando de dados MySql pelo `while`, dentro de um `for`, ele deveria passar diversas vezes pelo `while`, porém parece que ele faz somente uma 'varredura' na tabela e as próximas nem entra no `while`.

```html
....
<?php
$n = 1;
$prof = 9;
for($cprof = $n; $cprof <= $prof; $cprof++){
?>
          <td>
            <div>
<?php
while($ag = mysqli_fetch_assoc($agendamento)){
  echo 'teste';
};
?>
            </div>
          </td>
<?php
}
?>
....
```

Não sei se fui claro o suficiente, mas minha tabela no html tem varias linhas e colunas, após executar o código, ele imprime somente o 'teste' na primeira célula, nas próximas ele parece não fazer o `while`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você faz o while com o mysql_fetch, o ponteiro interno aponta para o primeiro registro dos resultados, e ele vai sendo incrementando até chegar o último registro.

Se você rodar uma segunda vez, o ponteiro já vai estar no último registro, portanto não vão haver registros para iterar.

Para resolver isso, você deve voltar o ponteiro para o primeiro registro utilizando a função mysqli_data_seek

O seu while ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
while($ag = mysqli_fetch_assoc($agendamento)){
  echo 'teste';
};
mysqli_data_seek($agendamento,0);
```